# python setdefault in setdefault behavior

Tags: python

I tries to understand how nested setdefault works in code. I know how the basic setdefault  works but I have a problem with figuring out such an code:

there are no keys in d, why both keys and values are added? "333" not in d so we're going to defult value d.setdefault("444",[]) -> we put a "444" key with a value [], setdefault return [] which we insert to "333" key which is returned by first setdefault and append is made(why for both new keys, I thought only for "333")

```
d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
d.setdefault("333", d.setdefault("444",[])).append("ddd") 
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': ['ddd'], '333': ['ddd']}
```

first is already in d, "ddd" is appended to the existing "111" key but why is there a new key "444"?

```
d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
d.setdefault("111", d.setdefault("444",[])).append("ddd") 
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': []}
```

first and the second key is already in d, only first updated?

```
d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
d.setdefault("111", d.setdefault("222",[])).append("ddd") 
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd'], '222': ['ccc']}
```

second is in d,..?

```
d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
d.setdefault("333", d.setdefault("222",[])).append("ddd") 
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc', 'ddd'], '333': ['ccc', 'ddd']}
```

thanks for the explanation

Comment: In all of the above cases, the "nested" call to `d.setdefault` will be executed **first** and **regardless** of the "outer" call. It is the same drawback of `d.get`, we don't have a "lazy" version out of the box.

Comment: Function arguments are never lazy in Python - they are always evaluated before the function is called. If you write `f(1, f(2, 3))` then the "second" function call *must* be evaluated first, in order to get a value for the second argument to the "first" function call.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
>>> d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
>>> first = d.setdefault("444",[])
>>> first
[]
>>> d
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': []}
>>> second = d.setdefault("333", first)
>>> second
[]
>>> d
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': [], '333': []}
>>> second.append("ddd")
>>> second
['ddd']
>>> d
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': ['ddd'], '333': ['ddd']}
```

Does that make it clear?

Note that `first` and `second` refer to the same list.

```
>>> first is second
True
>>> first.append('test')
>>> first
['ddd', 'test']
>>> second
['ddd', 'test']
>>> d
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': ['ddd', 'test'], '333': ['ddd', 'test']}
```

Comment: "first and second refer to the same list" - thx this is an important tip.


"dictionary.setdefault(keyname, value);      value - optional, If the key exist, this parameter has no effect."

d = {'111': ['aaa', 'bbb'], '222': ['ccc']}
d.setdefault("111", d.setdefault("444",[])).append("ddd") 
{'111': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd'], '222': ['ccc'], '444': []}

and in this case why is "444" added?

Comment: Because you issue `d.setdefault("444",[])`?

Comment: but key 111 exist and d.setdefault("444",[])  should be optional - ok but when it is a function it calculates it anyway

Comment: @Kriss did you read the comments under your question? `d.setdefault("444",[])` is executed first. It does not know that its return value will be used as the argument to another function call later.

Comment: ok, thanks, everything is clear